# How do I create daemon threads?

Tags: java, daemon

Can a java programmer can create daemon threads manually? How is it?

Comment: Do you mean "daemon" threads ? In which case, google can take you further..

Comment: Please note that this might not do what you're really after. A daemon thread isn't the same as a daemon process.

Comment: Biju and http://stackoverflow.com/users/124339/johanna are same person?

Comment: No i am a different person...

Comment: Stop flooding stackoverflow, go to your favourite search engine and use it, please.

Comment: Wow why the hate? Perfectly reasonable question assuming they wanted to create a daemon thread...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[java.lang.Thread.setDaemon(boolean)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean))

Note that if not set explicitly, this property is "inherited" from the Thread that creates a new Thread.

Answer (score 6):

You can mark a thread as a daemon using the setDaemon method provided. According to the java doc:

> Marks this thread as either a daemon thread or a user thread. The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads.
>
> This method must be called before the thread is started.
>
> This method first calls the checkAccess method of this thread with no arguments. This may result in throwing a SecurityException (in the current thread).

Here an example:

```
Thread someThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runSomething();
    }
});
someThread.setDaemon(true);
someThread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class mythread1 implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("hii i have set thread as daemon");
  }


  public static void main(String []arg) {
    mythread1 th=new mythread1();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(th);
    t1.setDaemon(true);
    t1.start();
    System.out.println(t1.isDaemon());
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Yes you can

```
Thread thread = new Thread(  
  new Runnable(){  
    public void run(){  
      while (true)
        wait_for_action();
    }  
  }  
);  
thread.start();
```

Comment: class Devil extends Thread { 
 
    Devil() { 
        setDaemon( true ); 
        start(); 
    } 
         
    public void run() { 
        // Perform evil tasks 
        ... 
    } 
} 
I got this one...
Have u heard about this..